# Is $(B - A)(A + B)$ symmetric if $A = A^T$ and $B = B^T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a problem where I have to say if a matrix is symmetric or not, if $A = A^T$ and $B = B^T$.
According to what I know, a matrix $A$ is symmetric if $A = A^T$.

---

The specific matrix I am a bit confused about is:

$$(B - A)(A + B)$$

One of the hints of the problem is to use the following properties of matrix transposition:

$$(A + B)^T = A^T + B^T \\
(AB)^T = B^TA^T$$

---

So this is my attempt:

I have to show that: $$(B - A)(A + B) = ((B - A)(A + B))^T$$

I know that:

$$((B - A)(A + B))^T = (A + B)^T(B - A)^T \\
(A + B)^T(B - A)^T = (A^T + B^T)(B^T - A^T) \\
(A^T + B^T)(B^T - A^T) = (A + B)(B - A) 
$$

In what cases $(A + B)(B - A) = (B - A)(A + B)$ ? It would be like $AB = BA$? Well, if either $A$ or $B$ are the $0$ matrix or $A$ is the inverse of $B$, right? Are there other situations?

So what can I conclude?

Comment: Multiply together all terms, exchange all transposes for the non-transposed factors.

Comment: It is important to note the order of multiplication using distributive laws for matrices, because they don't commute in general. For instance A(B+C) = AB + AC but not BA+AC

Comment: Rather than writing down the equation whose truth you're trying to prove (or refute), maybe start with the right-hand ("transposed") side. Distribute the product (as you say, matrices work just like real numbers, so long as you're careful about the order of factors), then replace each factor with its transpose (as mathreadler says) and see if the result factors into $(B - A)(A + B)$.

Comment: @Rinzler: Not exactly. :) You set up a "two-column" proof, starting from an identity you want to prove and manipulating each side. In my experience, this tends to confuse, because at the end it's easy to blur what was assumed and what has been shown. (It's also logically incorrect; in mathematics, you _never_ assume what you want to prove. Again, the very first line of your computation is the desired conclusion.) The computation in mathreadler's answer is the type of format I was describing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$((B-A)(A+B))^T = (A^T+B^T)(B^T-A^T) = A^TB^T - (A^T)^2 + (B^T)^2 +B^TA^T = /A^T = A, B^T = B/ = AB - A^2 + B^2 - BA$

As you say you get BA - AB instead in the lhs. So you need AB = BA. In other terms A and B must *commute*. In general there are quite strict rules for which matrices commute.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is correct, i.e. $(B-A)(A+B)$ is symmetric if $AB=BA$, and it's easy to continue your proof from what you've done already. Just expand your terms, simplify, and you will end up with $AB=BA$.

There are, however, counterexamples for the converse. For instance, take
\begin{align*}
A=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix},\qquad B=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}
Then 
\begin{align*}
(B-A)(A+b)=\begin{pmatrix}-1 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix},
\end{align*}
which is not symmetric. Note that in this case $AB\neq BA$.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, you need $AB=BA$, that is, $A$ and $B$ must commute.

While you don't explicitly say so, I assume this is about real matrices (that is, matrices whose entries are real numbers).

Since A and B are, by assumption, symmetric, they commute exactly if their eigenvectors are the same.