# Is $BABA$ a symmetric matrix, if $A = A^T$ and $B = B^T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is $BABA$ a symmetric matrix, if $A = A^T$ and $B = B^T$?

I have asked a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1189844/is-b-aa-b-symmetric-if-a-at-and-b-bt#comment2422606_1189844), but I am still having doubts (in general).

---

This is my solution:

We want to show that $BABA = (BABA)^T$.

Starting from the right side, we have that:

$$(BABA)^T = (BA)^T(BA)^T$$

Since we can consider $BA$ as a single term.

Now, we can do the same thing for each $(BA)^T$, so we have:

$$(BA)^T(BA)^T = (A^TB^T)(A^TB^T) = A^TB^TA^TB^T = ABAB$$

Since $A = A^T$ and $B = B^T$.

So, unless $A = B$, we have that the resulting matrix of the multiplication is not symmetric, right?

Comment: Yes. The whole point is that $A^T=A$ and $B^T=B$ does not necessarily entail $(AB)^T=AB$.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is NO. Take

$$A=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{array}\right),
B=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{array}\right)$$.

Then

$$
(BA)^2=BA=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{array}\right)
$$

is not symmetric.